# How to load the gatling configuration only once while executing the scenarios in Gatling?

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I am loading the application related config in BasicSimulation class and this class is being inherited by all other simulation test scripts in my project. This class contains something like this

[image]

> The sample simulation script is like below :

[image]

**Issues:**

1. For every **GET** request where I am using variable present in BasicSimulation class(i.e. header) it is initializing the **conf** every time. How can I fix this?
2. How can I call the existing scenarios present in different simulation classes i.e do I need to create the instance of each simulation class separately or is there any other way also?